# Doubt regarding sum of a subring and an ideal need not be subring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

We know that sum of two subrings need not be a subring, but then why is the following so:

> Let $A$ be a subring of a ring $R$ and $I$ an ideal of $R$ . Then  $A+I=\{a+i\mid a\in A,i\in I\}$ is a subring of $R$.

This was written in statement for second homomorphism theorem, but I can't understand why is $A+I$ a subring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R$ denote a not-necessarily commutative ring. Assume that $A \subseteq R$ is a subring and that $I \subseteq R$ is a two-sided ideal.

Let us show that $A+I$ is closed under products, since closure under addition is trivial, and so too is closure under unary negation (by which I mean the function $x \in R \mapsto -x \in R$). So suppose $x,y \in A+I$. Then $x=a+i$ and $y=a'+i'$ for appropriate choices of $a,a' \in A$ and $i,i' \in I$. So

$$xy = (a+i)(a'+i') = \underbrace{aa'}_{\in A}+\underbrace{ia'+ai'+ii'}_{\in I} \in A+I$$

So $A+I$ is closed under products.

We can write the above argument in more compact notation as follows:

$$(A+I)(A+I) = \underbrace{AA}_{\subseteq A}+\underbrace{IA+AI+II}_{\subseteq I} \subseteq A+I$$

**Remark.** If $R$ has a unity element $1,$ and if $1 \in A,$ then since $1+0 \in A+I$, hence $1 \in A+I$.

Comment: I can't deduce how to prove $ab^{-1}\in A+I$ for $a,b\in A+I$ to prove it is a subring..can you please help me out....

Comment: @coool, look at the definition of "ring" and "subring" again. There is no mention of $b^{-1}$, in fact reciprocals are not required to exist.

Comment: I meant $a-b\in A+I$

Comment: @coool, I prefer to just show $\dfrac{x,y \in A+I}{x+y \in A+I}$ and $\dfrac{x \in A+I}{-x \in A+I}$. These are both straightforward.

Comment: I can't get why did you replace the condition $a-b\in A+I$ by $x,y \in A+I \rightarrow x+y \in A+I$ and $x \in A+I \rightarrow -x \in A+I$

Comment: @coool, try to work it out yourself. Its really not that hard. Just make a note of the fact that, in ring theory, $x-y$ can be treated as shorthand for $x+-y$. In fact this works in any Abelian group. If its still not making sense after a good 20-30 mins of pondering and scrawling, consider asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method should work: just show closure under $0,1,+,-,\cdot$. It's hard to give any more advice than that without you showing why you're having problems: maybe you're forgetting the (usual) defining property of ideals?

For variety, another approach is to use the fact that if $f : R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism and $T \subseteq S$ is a subring, then $f^{-1}(T)$ is a subring of $R$.

Comment: I don't know How to prove $A+I$ closed under multiplication...to show it is subring..